# Left and right limit of $x^k \sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: limits

I want to prove that this function is differentiable.

So I'am looking at the left and right limit of:
$f_k(x) = x^k \sin(1/x)$ with $f(0) = 0$

So I am trying to evaluate with $x_{0} = 0$:

$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f_k(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = [...] = \lim_{h \to 0^+} h^{k-1}\sin(1/h) = \begin{cases}
0^{+} & k \neq 0 \\
\text{not defined} & \,  k=0 
\end{cases} $

$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f_k(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = [...] = \lim_{h \to 0^-} h^{k-1}\sin(1/h) = \begin{cases}
0^{-} & k = 2n \\
0^{+} & k = 2n+1 \\
\text{not defined} & k=0
\end{cases} $

So I would argue that the limit is defined for $k=2n+1$ at $0$. And do the limits even go toward $0^+$ and $0^-$ or just towards $0$?

Comment: Your title says $x^n\sin(1/n)$, and the body of the proof says $x^k\sin(1/x)$. Which is it?

Comment: The latter. Edited the title, thanks.

Comment: The limit, if exists, is either a real number or $\pm \infty$. $0^\pm$ are not numbers. By the way, you could just use the multiplication and chain rules for differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "$\sin(1/x)$" is a red herring.  Take any bounded function $g$ defined on a neighbourhood of $0$; in our case $g(x)=sin(1/x)$ for $\neq0$ and $g(0)=42$.  Then $f(x)=x^kg(x)$ is differentiable if $k\geq2$ as
$$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0}{h}=\frac{h^kg(h)}{h}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$0^+$ is not a number, and saying $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0^+$$ is not really standard notation.

What is standard notation is writing something like

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = L$$

which would mean that $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $0$ from *above*.

---

However, the limit of a function, **by definition**, can only ever be a real number or $\infty$ or $-\infty$. So, in your case, the limit you want is $0$ even when $k=2n$.